# Recommendation system with active learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, recommender-system, active-learning

I have data where companies ask users to score a bunch of questions but some items may be randomly chosen while others are personalized. Users score higher in personalized questions on average. I have a user ID, question ID, corresponding score of the question by the user, and whether the question is random or personalized.

I want to build a recommendation system that incorporates the feature of a question being random or personalized.

I assume that for a personalized item to appear there must be some learning of previous random questions the company learned about the user beforehand.

But I got quite lost in terms of how to have a recommendation system that incorporates the dynamic structure.

I know basic recommendation includes matrix factorization or embedding for a user-item matrix but I don’t know how to accommodate the learning.

I would appreciate any insights/pointing to relevant literature/relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach recommendation systems that can change over time based on user input is to model them with [Reinforcement Learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinforcement_learning). There is an inherent notion of time and active choices with Reinforcement Learning.

Contextual-Bandit is a popular approach that models information about the user (context) to influence which options (arms of the bandit) are shown to a user.